Creating UV Map with Swift and MetalKit
I am performing LiDAR scanning using Swift with Metal and ARKit. I am able to export my files in PLY, OBJ, and MTL formats, but I need to export the UV map of the scanned area in JPG format.
I’m trying to create a UV texture map for a 3D model using Swift, but I’m having trouble figuring out how to proceed. My goal is to calculate and apply the necessary UV coordinates to correctly map textures onto the surface of a 3D model.
Has anyone worked on this before, or could someone guide me in the right direction? For example, I’m looking for recommendations on which frameworks to use, how to implement UV mapping algorithms, or any sample code that could help.
Thank you in advance!

This has literally nothing to do with Metal, ARKit or Swift. This is just a problem of generating a UV unwrap.

@Spo1ler I need to solve this with whatever technology is required in the iPad or iOS device internally. I think this is possible, but I couldn't find any sources.

The only thing I can think of is addUnwrappedTextureCoordinatesForAttributeNamed in MDLMesh in Model I/O. There's no "technology" here, you just have to come up with source code to do this. There are probably open-source libraries that do UV unwraps.
